# Regex expression to match and store matched groups in an array

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group, string-matching

```
    let str = `!img2.png|width=83.33333333333334%!
    
                 !robot (f05f0216-caf4-4543-a630-99c2477849d5).png|width=400,height=400!
    
             fefeeef         !abc.pdf|width=200!
    
            !dfe.xlx           !abcd.xlx!
    `
    
    let str = str.replace(/\!(.*(jpg|png|gif|pdf|xlx))|(|width=})!\]/gm, function (match, capture) 
   {
                let imageConfig = [];
             //match and push in array
                imageConfig.push({file: 'abc.jpg' , width: 100, height:200});
                 
                return str; 
            })
                 
   Expected o/p:-
     imageConfig = [{file: 'abc.jpg' , width: 100, height:200}, {file: 'cdf.pdf' , width: 
                                200}, ....]
```

This is what I tried, but regex is not giving correct match and its matched group:-

https://regex101.com/r/V6cA4i/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to build your output:

```
/!([^|!]*(?:jpe?g|png|gif|pdf|xlx))(?:\|width=(\d*\.?\d+%?)(?:,height=(\d*\.?\d+%?))?)?!/g
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V6cA4i/3)

**Code and Demo:**

```js
let str = `!img2.png|width=83.33333333333334%!
    
                 !robot (f05f0216-caf4-4543-a630-99c2477849d5).png|width=400,height=400!
    
             fefeeef         !abc.pdf|width=200!
    
            !dfe.xlx           !abcd.xlx!`;
            
var re = /!([^|!]*(?:jpe?g|png|gif|pdf|xlx))(?:\|width=(\d*\.?\d+%?)(?:,height=(\d*\.?\d+%?))?)?!/g;
    
let m;
let imageConfig = [];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  imageConfig.push({file: m[1] , width: (m[2] || ''), height: (m[3] || '')});
}
console.log(imageConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, !abcd.xlx! . This scenario should also work.

Comment: sure, check my updated answer and new demo

Answer (score 1):

**The | needs to be escaped**

You have to escape the `|` character that precedes "width":

Corrected regex:

```
!(.*(jpg|png|gif|pdf|xlx))\|(width=.+)!
```

You do not have to escape the `!` at the beginning according to regex101. Feel free to add `\!` again if your regex dialect needs it.

**Optional width**

In case only height is given we should check for given width or height:

```
!(.*(jpg|png|gif|pdf|xlx))(\|((width|height)=.+)!)?
```

Comment: The expression works, but grouped element should only include  (abc.png) or (width=200) or (height=100)

Comment: If you need height to be optional you must group `(width|height)` together, otherwise the `|` will not work. The last `?` checks if the `|width` is even there, otherwise your last example will not work. You must use a group around the whole expression. AFAIK regex groups will always result in an entry in the result, even if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach uses a combination of two regular expressions, one for retrieving/[matching the raw file data](https://regex101.com/r/XLNGBp/1) ...

```
/[!"]+([^!"]+)[!"]/gm
```

... and a second one in order to [help processing the final data structure](https://regex101.com/r/XLNGBp/3) ...

```
/^(?<fileName>[^.]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|pdf|xlx))(?:\|(?:width=(?<width>.*?))?,?(?:height=(?<height>.*?))?)?$/
```

Both reg-expressions use [Capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) the second one does it via [named groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) in order to create the final data structure just by [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) where the latter is used to only assign fields like `width` and `height` in case they actually could be retrieved.

There are 3 example loggings, stepwise progressing the data handling in order to give an idea of all involved data processing steps ...

```js
const sampleText = `!img2.png|width=83.33333333333334%!

             "!robot (f05f0216-caf4-4543-a630-99c2477849d5).png|width=400,height=400!" 

                  "!abc.pdf|width=200!"

        "!dfe.xlx"
  !"dfe.gif|height=400!"`;

// [https://regex101.com/r/XLNGBp/1]
const regXRawFileData = (/[!"]+([^!"]+)[!"]/gm);

// [https://regex101.com/r/XLNGBp/3]
const regXFileData = (/^(?<fileName>[^.]+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|pdf|xlx))(?:\|(?:width=(?<width>.*?))?,?(?:height=(?<height>.*?))?)?$/);

console.log(
  'match all data ...',

  Array.from(
    sampleText.matchAll(regXRawFileData)
  ).map(([match, rawData]) => rawData)
);
console.log(
  'match and filter all valid raw file data ...',

  [...sampleText.matchAll(regXRawFileData)]
    .map(([match, rawData]) => rawData)

    .filter(str => regXFileData.test(str))
);
console.log(
  'match, filter and map all valid file data ...',

  [...sampleText.matchAll(regXRawFileData)]
    .map(([match, rawData]) => rawData)

    .filter(str => regXFileData.test(str))
    .map(str => {
      const { fileName:file, width, height } = regXFileData.exec(str).groups;
      return {
        file,
        ...(width && { width } || {}),
        ...(height && { height } || {}),
      };
    })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```